# SQL Server Management Studio: The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm taking a SQL class, and on one of the assignments I am asked to create a table with employees, one with projects, as follows:

```
create table [EMPLOYEE]
(
    EmployeeID int identity(1, 1) primary key not null,
    FirstName varchar(15) not null,
    LastName varchar(15) not null,
    Gender char(1) not null,
    DOB date not null,
    SSN char(9) not null
)

create table [PROJECT]
(
    ProjectID int identity(1, 1) primary key not null,
    Manager int not null,
    PDescription varchar(50) not null,
    PStatus varchar(20) not null,
    StartDate date not null,
    EndDate date not null
)
```

Where the `Manager` is the `ID` of an `EMPLOYEE` entity. Basically projects are assigned to employees. So, I add some employees and projects

```
insert into EMPLOYEE (FirstName, LastName, Gender, DOB, SSN)
values ('Chuck', 'Carter', 'M', '07/14/1990', '444556666')
```

This is the one employee I'm interested in, and in the inserting I'm doing this is the second one, so its `EmployeeID` would be 2. As for the projects:

```
insert into PROJECT (Manager, PDescription, PStatus, StartDate, EndDate)
values (2, 'Submit source code for 3D racing game', 'In progress', '01/05/2015', '03/05/2015')

insert into PROJECT (Manager, PDescription, PStatus, StartDate, EndDate)
values (2, 'Test videogame for bugs', 'Not started', '03/05/2015', '05/05/2015')
```

These two are the ones assigned to the employee above, notice Manager for both is 2, and the `EmployeeID` of Chuck is supposed to be 2. So, I'm supposed to display the employee name as a full name, combining the first and last name, of those who have been assigned two or more projects (in this case, Chuck).

I wrote this code:

```
select 
    FirstName + LastName as FullName 
from 
    EMPLOYEE
where 
    EmployeeID = PROJECT.Manager and count(PROJECT.Manager) >= 2
```

But instantly I get this error:

> The multi-part identifier "PROJECT.Manager" could not be bound.

Am I supposed to make an inner join to recognize the `PROJECT` table? But I'm only supposed to display the name of the employee. How can I manage to use the `PROJECT.manager` column values without displaying them?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You need to join, or do `from EMPLOYEE, PROJECT`. You're not identifying the PROJECT table in the select statement, so the where clause doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Join `Project` table, Add `Group by` with `having` clause to filter the `Manager`

```
select FirstName +' '+ LastName as FullName 
from EMPLOYEE
INNER JOIN PROJECT
on EmployeeID = PROJECT.Manager
group by FirstName +' '+ LastName
Having count(PROJECT.Manager) >= 2
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to separate this with a space?